# Change default delimiters in ember.js

Tags: templates, ember.js, web2py

(This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128593/processing-ember-js-tagged-html-with-python))

I have a web2py application which I want to extend with some ember.js code. The delimiters of the templating systems in web2py and ember.js conflict (both are `{{` and `}}`). Since my application has no ember.js legacy, I would like to write the ember.js code using a different delimiter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template engine use by ember.js is Handlebars.js, and I don't think you can change the delimiter.
I've seen the other question, and perhaps an other answer could be found here : [Handlebars.js in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229484/handlebars-js-in-django-templates/7232482#7232482)

Comment: Thanks. Since ember.js in inflexible in this regard, and web2py is configurable, I am forced to change the default delimiters in web2py, and process all my view files.

Comment: What a pity, I thought you could do the same as in this answer about django, ie defining a kind of block delimeters where you can put handlebars templates. So you would'nt have to change your actual files... :(

Answer (score 3):

In web2py:  response.delimiters = ('[[',']]')

Comment: Thanks Massimo, that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change any delimiters (on web2py or in handlebars) you can do it by saving the handlebars template in an external file like **people.hbs** in the 
web2py /static/ folder for example

```
{{#each people}}
<div class="person">
    <h2>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</h2>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

And in the view import that file using [jQuery load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/master/dist/handlebars.js"></script>    

<div id="list"></div>
<script id="people-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#people-template').load('/static/people.hbs', function() {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#people-template").html());
    var data = {
        people: [
            { first_name: "Alan", last_name: "Johnson" },
            { first_name: "Allison", last_name: "House" },
        ]
    };
    $('#list').html(template(data));
});
</script>
```